# How do I correctly create dependencies between targets in CMake?

Tags: c++, build, cmake

I am trying to use CMake to set up some simple dependencies between a C++ project and the libraries that it uses.

The set up is as follows

- Project

  - Dependency

Project itself contains source files that include headers from `Dependency` and when the executable is built it needs to be linked against `Dependency`'s static library.

So far I can get this to work, but I have to specify the include directories of `Dependency` in the `CMakeLists.txt` file for `Project` manually. I want this to be pulled out automatically, and I have explored the option of using the `find_package()` command to do so with limited success and making things much more complicated.

All I want to do is have `Dependency` built before `Project` and have `Project` link against the library and have its include directories. Is there a simple concise way of achieving this?

My current CMake files:

`Project`, file `CMakeLists.txt`:

```
cmake_minimum_required (VERSION 2.6)
project (Project)
include_directories ("${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/Project")
add_subdirectory (Dependency)
add_executable (Project main.cpp)
target_link_libraries (Project Dependency)
add_dependencies(Project Dependency)
```

`Dependency`, file `CMakeLists.txt`:

```
project(Dependency)
add_library(Dependency SomethingToCompile.cpp)
target_link_libraries(Dependency)
```

Comment: Checkout: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10004134/cmake-add-dependency-not-in-subdirectory

Answer (score 29):

Since `CMake 2.8.11` you can use `target_include_directories`. Just simply add in your DEPENDENCY project this function and fill in include directories you want to see in the main project. CMake will care the rest.

PROJECT, CMakeLists.txt:

```
cmake_minimum_required (VERSION 2.8.11)
project (Project)
include_directories (Project)
add_subdirectory (Dependency)
add_executable (Project main.cpp)
target_link_libraries (Project Dependency)
```

DEPENDENCY, CMakeLists.txt

```
project (Dependency)
add_library (Dependency SomethingToCompile.cpp)
target_include_directories (Dependency PUBLIC include)
```

Comment: The `add_subdirectory` always computes `Dependency` irregardless of wither it is being reference or not. How do you express it such that, `Dependency` is only computed when `Project` references it in `target_link_libraries`?

Answer (score 2):

It is not exactly clear what you want to do, and why `Project` and `Dependency` have to be build separately.

My first though on your example would be

1. In `PROJECT`'s `CMakeLists.txt`:

   - Remove `add_dependencies(Project Dependency)`
     There is no need to specify dependency, `target_link_libraries()` already does that.
2. In `DEPENDENCY`'s  `CMakeLists.txt`:

   - Remove  `project(Dependency)`
     It builds a library, so why to have own project?
   - Remove `target_link_libraries(Dependency)`
     Because it does nothing

Comment: to answer your question. Dependency might be a project for a shared library that is included as a git submodule. The shared library is meant to work also without the outer project.