# Add a dependency not in a subdirectory using CMake

Tags: cmake

Let's say there's following directory structure:

```
root
  |
  +--projects
  |      |
  |      +-test
  |         |
  |         +-CMakeFiles.txt
  |
  +--libs
       |
       +-testlib
            |
            +-CMakeFiles.txt
```

`test` contains `CMakeFiles.txt` and `testlib` also contains `CMakeFiles.txt`. "test" produces an executable and "testlib" produces a static library.

I want "test" to link with "testlib" without using symlinks and without moving "testlib" library into a subdirectory within "test".

Because "testlib" isn't a subdirectory of "test", I can't do

```
add_subdirectory("../../libs/testlib")
```

In test's `CMakeFiles.txt` - CMake will complain about "testlib" not being in the "test" subdirectory.

Also, because system has several different compilers, I can't simply install "testlib" libraries into some kind of central directory, so I want `test` to compile a local copy of `testlib` and link with it (i.e. as if `testlib` was a subdirectory). I also want the "test" project to automatically rebuild "testlib" if it has been changed.

So, how can I deal with it? I am using CMake 2.8.4 on Windows XP SP3.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You could either provide a top-level CMakeLists.txt in `root`, or provide a binary directory to the `add_subdirectory` command; e.g.

```
add_subdirectory("../../libs/testlib" "${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/testlib_build")
```

This creates a subdirectory called `testlib_build` in your current build directory which contains the generated project files for testlib, but not the source.

For further info, run

```
cmake --help-command ADD_SUBDIRECTORY
```

Comment: @Fraser - Is it possible to specify binary directory in testlib_build's CMakeFile?

Comment: @tower120 - No, you'd need to specify it in the `add_subdirectory` call.

Answer (score 14):

The only way I see to do this - create `CMakeLists.txt` in root and put the following code there:

```
add_subdirectory(projects/test)
add_subdirectory(lib/testlib)
```

When you have done this, you can do `target_link_libraries(test testlib)` in `test/CMakeLists.txt`, and it will be automatically rebuilt if you change something in `testlib`.