# Including a static library in CMAKE from a different folder for an Android Project

Tags: android, c++, android-studio, cmake, static-libraries

I am trying to convert my Android NDK cpp projects (ndk-build with Android.mk) to CMAKE in Android Studio. I have a project hierarchy like this:

```
.
├── Module1
│   ├── CMakeLists.txt
│   ├── include
│   │   └── Module1
│   ├── libModule1
│   │   ├── Module1File1.cpp
│   │   └── Module1File2.cpp
│   └── utModule1
├── MyProject
│   ├── CMakeLists.txt
│   ├── MyProject.iml
│   ├── build
│   │   ├── generated
│   │   ├── intermediates
│   │   └── outputs
│   ├── build.gradle
│   ├── proguard-rules.pro
│   └── src
│       │
│       ├── MyProjectFile1.cpp
│       └── MyProjectFile2.cpp
|
└── settings.gradle
```

**Module1 CMakeLists.txt:**

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.4.1)
add_library( # Specifies the name of the library.
             Module1

             # Sets the library as a shared library.
             STATIC

             # Provides a relative path to your source file(s).
             libModule1/Module1File1.cpp
             libModule1/Module1File2.cpp )
```

**MyProject CMakeLists.txt:**

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.4.1)

add_subdirectory(../MyModule1)

add_library( # Specifies the name of the library.
             MyProject
             # Sets the library as a shared library.
             SHARED
             # Provides a relative path to your source file(s).
             src/MyProjectFile1.cpp
             src/MyProjectFile2.cpp)

target_link_libraries( # Specifies the target library.
        MyProject
        # Dependencies
        MyModule1
        # Links the target library to the log library
        # included in the NDK.
        ${log-lib})
```

I am seeing the following error when I build:

```
CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt (add_subdirectory):
```

How do I include MyModule1 into MyProject?

Comment: [Possible duplicate of](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10004134/add-a-dependency-not-in-a-subdirectory-using-cmake)

Comment: You forgot to include the rest of the error message into the question post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suggested fix from:

[Add a dependency not in a subdirectory using CMake](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10004134/add-a-dependency-not-in-a-subdirectory-using-cmake)

worked for me.

```
include_directories(../MyMModule1/include/)
add_subdirectory("../MyMModule1/" "${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/MyModule1_build")
```