# Cannot find library with simple C++ example

Tags: c++, cmake, ld

I am building a C++ library called `alpha` in Ubuntu with cmake, which contains one source file:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8)

project(Alpha)

add_library (alpha alpha.cpp)
```

This creates a file called `libalpha.a`, which I now want to link to. So, I copy it into the source directory of another C++ projected called `beta`, which also contains one source file:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8)

project(Beta)

add_executable(beta beta.cpp)

target_link_libraries(beta alpha)
```

However, I get the following error:

```
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lalpha
```

The same thing happens if I use the line:

```
target_link_libraries(beta libalpha.a)
```

Why can `beta` not find the `alpha` library?

Comment: You may need to add `link_directories(the_directory_where_you_put_the_library)`.

Comment: But the library has been copied to the same directory as `beta.cpp`...

Comment: Have you tried `target_link_libraries(beta ./libalpha.a)` ?

Comment: Yes, that gives me the error: `/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -l./libalpha.a`

Comment: maybe add a line: `link_directories(${Beta_SOURCE_DIR})` ?

Comment: I believe this should do what you want: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4905089/cmake-how-to-correctly-create-dependencies-between-targets

Comment: take a look here: http://www.cs.swarthmore.edu/~newhall/unixhelp/howto_C_libraries.html

Answer (score 0):

If you wish to build the library and the program completely separately, you have to use [imported targets](http://www.cmake.org/Wiki/CMake/Tutorials/Exporting_and_Importing_Targets). When you try to link your executable against a "completely unknown" library, CMake build system automatically passes the task of locating the library to the linker, simply adding `-lalpha` option. When the linker encounters the option it attempts to locate libalpha.so in one of the standard library locations (i.e. `/usr/lib/`, `/usr/local/lib` etc) and expectedly fails. You can use an absolute path to the `libalpha.a`: `target_link_libraries(beta /path/to/libalpha.a)`.

However if you can build things together, this greatly simplifies the task. Consider

<project>/CMakeLists.txt:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8)

Project(Test)

add_subdirectory(alpha)
add_subdirectory(beta)
```

<project>/alpha/CMakeLists.txt

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8.11)

project(alpha)

set(SOURCES alpha.c)

add_library(alpha ${SOURCES})
target_include_directories(
  alpha INTERFACE
  "$<BUILD_INTERFACE:${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}>"
  "$<BUILD_INTERFACE:${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}>"
)
```

`target_include_directories()` with the complex expression within is required to automatically add libalpha include directories to all components which later are linked against libalpha.

<project>/beta/CMakeLists.txt

```
project(beta)

set(SOURCES beta.c)

add_executable(beta ${SOURCES})
target_link_libraries(beta alpha)
```

Answer (score 0):

Add this line with the path to alpha-library.

```
link_directories( <library path> )
```