# CMake always recompiling dependencies

Tags: c++, cmake

I have a library my project depends on, I check out this `submodule` with `git --recursive` and then include it in my CMakeLists.txt file:

```
add_subdirectory(dependencies/library)
add_executable(myExe ...)
add_dependencies(myExe library)
target_link_libraries(myExe library)
```

### The problem:

**library** is a pretty big library and recompiling it takes an awful lot of time.

I practically NEVER change it so it should be built once, but CMake is recompiling it every time I add a single line to the CMakeLists.txt file and refresh the Visual Studio solution entirely.

How to avoid this horrible behavior and tell CMake NOT to recompile **library** if nothing changed into it?

Comment: well, I guess the the library's CMakeLists is written incorrectly. If one of the targets within `dependencies/library/CMakeLists.txt` is considered out-of-date due to whatever reason, you would get this particular behaviour. Please demostrate us that `CMakeLists.txt` and let's speculate what can be wrong with it and what can be fixed.

Comment: I would suspect an improperly described code generation, but the reasons might be much, much weirder.

Comment: Does your `dependencies/library/CMakeLists.txt` also contain a `project()` command? This is just a wild guess, but it could be one reason for this behavior. Generally speaking - for a huge external library - you could think about using [`ExternalProject_Add()`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.4/module/ExternalProject.html) (see e.g. [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33443164/cmake-share-library-with-multiple-executables))

Comment: I'm voting to close because I don't think there's enough info here to answer the question. There's no repro. The SMEs commenting above are all reduced to guessing what could be the problem.