# Using project() for dependent CMake subdirectories

Tags: cmake, project, subdirectory

I have several projects consisting of a few libraries, each living in its own subdirectory, knitted together by the topmost `CMakeLists.txt` file. I am in the habit of using `project(<DIRNAME>)` at the top of each `CMakeLists.txt` file and I try to structure the subprojects in such a way that they could be compiled separately from the top project. However, while this might make sense for standalone, core libraries, it cannot work for the libraries that depend on them because I need to do stuff like

```
target_link_libraries(gui core)
```

And `core` will nor be defined if I am trying to compile `gui` as a standalone project.

Is it wrong to use `project()` in this context, or am I missing something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**A Matter of Taste**

This is in my opinion mainly a matter of taste. I don't think multiple `project()` commands itself are a problem, its more that projects I have seen using this approach tend to repeat itself in other parts and sometimes are running into problems with global cached variables.

**Depending Libraries**

The more relevant fact is, that the depending libraries will also add an include dependencies.

For standalone static library targets - not executable or shared library targets who really link the library - the simple `target_link_libraries()` command could be ignored with something like:

```
if (TARGET core)
    target_link_libraries(gui core)
endif()
```

But the header files include dependency remains.

**Standalone Projects in CMake**

For me a (sub-)project to be really standalone needs not only the `project()` command, but it should also have a `export(TARGETS ...)` command. Then you could e.g. use `find_package()` commands to resolve any open dependencies with something like:

```
if (NOT TARGET core)
    find_package(core REQUIRED)
endif()
target_link_libraries(gui core)
```

**References**

- [Making cmake library accessible by other cmake packages automatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33462209/making-cmake-library-accessible-by-other-cmake-packages-automatically)
- [CMake share library with multiple executables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33443164/cmake-share-library-with-multiple-executables)

Comment: Makes sense. The `export` solution is probably the way to go.

Comment: Just a quick note: I'm pretty sure `if(NOT TARGET ...)` will only work if the dependency directory is processed before this directory (e.g. `add_subdirectory(core)` must come before `add_subdirectory(thisone)`). Instead of `if(NOT TARGET...)`, in my implementation I check for the dependant directory to exist.