# Cmake: read variables from another (processed) directory

Tags: scope, cmake

I am trying to interrogate the inclusion path of a series of addsubdirectories():

```
-projectA
    -projectB
        -projectC
```

In this setup, `projectA` is adding `ProjectB` as a subdirectory which in turn adds `ProjectC` as a subdirectory. I want to let `projectC` know about the hierarchy.
I can achieve this by recursive calls

```
get_directory_property(parent DIRECTORY ${cur_dir} PARENT_DIRECTORY)
```

which will return nothing when it reaches `projectA`. That almost does it. It would be nice however, if I could read the `${PROJECT_NAME}` from these directories and return `A-B-C` instead of `projectA-projectB-projectC`.

So my question is: Is there any way of reading the variables from a directory that is already parsed?

Note that in this case, although `projectC` would inherit variables from its parent, but the standard cache variables are replaced in the child projects, which is why I can't use them.

Comment: Could [`LISTFILE_STACK`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.3/prop_dir/LISTFILE_STACK.html) be of any use here? Or you could have your own `my_add_subdirectory()` building the stack in custom directory properties from `PROJECT_NAME`. And did I understand correctly that all (sub-)folders have a `project()` command?

Comment: yeah all have project(). I am however reaching to the conclusion that the same way installed projects can have config files, I can have one generated with `configure_file` and place it in the source folder to act as a header or project file. so that having located the directory, I would just include its project file. I think its much cleaner than anything else I could do.

Comment: Ok, but how to setup this is most probably another question (see e.g. mine [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31512485/cmake-how-to-setup-source-library-and-cmakelists-txt-dependencies)). Just going by the main question you have asked here, yes you can read [`VARIABLES`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.3/prop_dir/VARIABLES.html) property for a specific already parsed directory.

Comment: That would only give you a list of variables. But thanks! I had another look and turns out "DEFINITIONS" would do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can do:

```
get_directory_property(output DIRECTORY dir/path DEFINITION PROJECT_NAME)
```

or any normal variable:

```
get_directory_property(output DIRECTORY dir/path DEFINITION myVariable)
```