# How to use add_dependency with CMake to non-subdirectories?

Tags: c, build, cmake

I have the following structure:

```
${root}
    project_a
        main.c
        CMakeLists.txt
    project_b
        lib.c
        target.cmake
```

CMakeList.txt

```
include(${ROOT}/project_b/target.cmake)

add_executable(${PROJECT_NAME} main.c)
add_dependencies (${PROJECT_NAME} app_cmake_b)
target_link_libraries (${PROJECT_NAME} app_cmake_b)
```

target.cmake

```
add_library(project_b STATIC ${ROOT}/lib.c)
```

Is using include the only way to import other cmake projects?

I do not like that I need absolute paths in my included `target.cmake`
What is the best pratice to solve my usecase with CMake?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [CMake: How to setup Source, Library and CMakeLists.txt dependencies?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31512485/cmake-how-to-setup-source-library-and-cmakelists-txt-dependencies)

Answer (score 1):

You should use the `add_subdirectory` function.

https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.0/command/add_subdirectory.html

You can add directories that are not subdirectories by using a relative path.

For example, if you want to add a sibling directory,

```
 add_subdirectory(../dir)
```

Simply make sure that the directory you place in the function has a `CMakeLists.txt`, and that will import that project into the current one.

Comment: I would but it's no subdirectory ... It does not work.

Comment: @Tarion I edited to explain that you can add a directory that is not a subdirectory.

Comment: Thanks for the hin. I like to have absolute paths for some reason. But found that this is working well: `add_subdirectory(${ROOT}/project_b ${ROOT}/pkg/project_b)`.

Answer (score 1):

Also, you can use ExternalProject module
https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.7/module/ExternalProject.html

```
ExternalProject_Add(project_b SOURCE_DIR "path" BINARY_DIR "path" ...)
```