# CMAKE library / application structure

Tags: c++, cmake

I have the following project structure:

```
root/
   CMakeLists.txt
   src/
      CMakeLists.txt
      engine/
         CMakeLists.txt
         *.h
         *.cpp
      console/
         CMakeLists.txt
         *.h
         *.cpp
```

Now in `src/engine/CMakeLists.txt` I call `add_library(engine ${SOURCES})` and it works out fine, compiles and everything. Now over in console, I would like my includes to the engine be `#include "engine/foo.h"` and not just `#include "foo.h"`.

Now the question is, are there any elegant way to add the includes so I have to prepend engine to my includes in the console project?

Currently what I do is have the following in `src/console/CMakeLists.txt`:

```
add_executable(console ${SOURCES})

target_include_directories(console PUBLIC ${lib_incl_path})
target_link_libraries(console PRIVATE engine)
```

and then define `set(lib_incl_path ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR})` in `src/CMakeLists.txt`. But that seems overkill (and hacky), to add the entire src folder to the includes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is to use

```
target_include_directories(${PROJECT_NAME} PUBLIC ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/..)
```

See [CMake how to correctly create dependencies between targets](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4905089/cmake-how-to-correctly-create-dependencies-between-targets)