# Cmake with multiple directories

Tags: c++, cmake

```
project
  |------ CMakeLists.txt (The main Cmake)
  |------ somePlace/someOtherPlace/CmakeLists.txt
  |          |----- some.proto (google proto files)
  |          |----- CMakeList.txt
  |------ Project2/CmakeListst.txt
             |----- .cpp files
             |----- .hpp files
             |----- CMakeList.txt
```

I have a similar topology as above, my main cmake could be able to generate cmake files, and after the main cmake I could be able to build Project2 with:

```
make Project2
```

I have added Project2 as subdirectory to the main cmake. I have no problem here. But I also want to build `common/someplace/CmakeLists.txt` together with the Project2, when I run `make Project2`. I also know that I could be able to build `common/someplace/CmakeLists.txt` inside its directory by cmake and make commands. You can check `somePlace/someOtherPlace/CmakeLists.txt` :

```
    INCLUDE(FindProtobuf)
    FIND_PACKAGE(Protobuf REQUIRED)
    INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES(${PROTOBUF_INCLUDE_DIR})
    PROTOBUF_GENERATE_CPP(PROTO_SRC PROTO_HEADER oamc_packets.proto)
    ADD_LIBRARY(proto ${PROTO_HEADER} ${PROTO_SRC})
```

But I want Project2 to depend on `somePlace/someOtherPlace/CmakeList.txt` and build together with it.How can I achieve it?

Should I use `add_executable/add_library` commands? The problem is `somePlace/someOtherPlace/CmakeLists.txt` creates header and cc file along with the .a file.

*PS: I can give further information, if it is requested.*

Comment: Add `common/someplace/` as subdirectory? And accordingly add a dependency in `Project2` on `common/someplace`'s target

Comment: Yes, I added somePlace/someOtherPlace/ as subdirectory. But how can I add a dependency in Project 2? @AlexeyLarionov

Comment: The directory structure of your CMake files has relatively little impact on the resulting build system. Can you show which targets are defined where? Targets are defined by `add_executable` and `add_library` (or `add_custom_target` if you're doing something exotic...)

Comment: @Botje As AlexeyLarinov comment, cant I just add a dependency to my Project2? I believe it will do it for me, however, I couldn't find a proper example thats fits my case. I have couple nested sub-directories, because of this this example didn't do it for me: *https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4905089/how-do-i-correctly-create-dependencies-between-targets-in-cmake*

Comment: You can add a dependency, but you need a target defined by either `add_executable`/`add_library`, as Botje suggested

Comment: @AlexeyLarionov I am not sure if it is a executable or a library, it is Google Proto file, when it is built, it generates some headers and cc files. Becuase of this I couldn't be sure how to do it?

Comment: Does it generate the files during configure stage or build stage? If the latter, I would expect some `add_custom_target` to be used by them atleast

Comment: I added the CmakeFileLists.txt as above.

Answer (score 0):

I peeked into the [documentation of `FindProtobuf`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/module/FindProtobuf.html#command:protobuf_generate_cpp), and they put a warning here

> Note: The `protobuf_generate_cpp` and `protobuf_generate_python` functions and `add_executable()` or `add_library()` calls only work properly within the same directory.

So perhaps if you could include the content of `somePlace/someOtherPlace/CmakeList.txt` inside your `Project2/CmakeListst.txt`, then you could safely use the generated file.

I can't really test the following code, but maybe in `Project2/CmakeListst.txt` before using the generated files you can do

```
include("${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/../somePlace/someOtherPlace/CmakeLists.txt")
```

Comment: Yes, Mr. Because of the note in the documentation, I am using cmake inside the somePlace/someOtherPlace/CmakeList.txt. I updated the question a little, the cmake file uses add_library as you said. I missed it. I will try you suggestion and update you

Comment: The problem is how can I *make*  somePlace/someOtherPlace/CmakeList.txt with the main CmakeList